# Trouble Converting JPanel to JApplet

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, japplet

This works fine when I have JPanel in Place of JApplet but I want it to run on a webpage. Am I missing something required for JApplet? From the error message my best guess is that I can't draw graphics2d based off the errors but It seems weird. When I run it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
    at koopa.draw(koopa.java:144)
    at koopa.paint(koopa.java:136)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

-

```
import java.applet.Applet;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.*;
    public class koopa extends JApplet implements KeyListener,
            ActionListener {

        // DECLARE ALL INSTANCE VARIABLES HERE..

        private ArrayList<Rectangle> aliens = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
        private Astronaut Luigi = new Astronaut(140, 508);
        private static Astronaut Mario = new Astronaut(200, 508);
        public static final Rectangle BORDER = new Rectangle(0, 0, 980, 620);
        private int frameCount;// used for the score
        private String title = "~~ Escape From The Koopas ~~  .. (click here first) .. "
                + "CONTROLS: arrows = move, space = jump, r = restart .. ..........";
        private Timer timer;// handles animation
        private static Image offScreenBuffer;// needed for double buffering graphics
        private Graphics offScreenGraphics;// needed for double buffering graphics
        private int highScore = 0;
        private boolean mAlive = true;
        private boolean lAlive = true;
        private int mWins = 0;
        private int lWins = 0;
        private Font f = new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 16);
        private BufferedImage[] img = new BufferedImage[10];

        /**
         * main() is needed to initialize the window.<br>
         * THIS METHOD SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED! .. <br>
         * you should write all necessary initialization code in initRound()
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame window = new JFrame("Escape From Rectangulus");
            window.setBounds(100, 100, 980, 630);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setResizable(false);

            koopa game = new koopa();
            game.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            window.getContentPane().add(game);
            window.setVisible(true);
            game.init();
            window.addKeyListener(game);

        }

        /**
         * init method needed to initialize non-static fields<br>
         * THIS METHOD SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED! ..
         */
        public void init() {
            offScreenBuffer = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());// should be
                                                                    // 800x400
            offScreenGraphics = offScreenBuffer.getGraphics();
            timer = new Timer(30, this);
            // timer fires every 30 milliseconds.. invokes method actionPerformed()
            // luigi sprites
            try {
                img[0] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("luigiRunLeft.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                img[1] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("luigiRunRight.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                img[2] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("luigiJumpLeft.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                img[3] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("luigiJumpRight.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // mario sprites
            try {
                img[4] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("marioRunLeft.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                img[5] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("marioRunRight.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                img[6] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("marioJumpLeft.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                img[7] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("marioJumpRight.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                img[8] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("koopa.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                img[9] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("bg.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            initRound();
        }

        /**
         * initializes all fields needed for each round of play (i.e. restart)
         */
        public void initRound() {
            frameCount = 0;
            Luigi = new Astronaut(140, 460);
            Mario = new Astronaut(200, 460);
            aliens = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
            mAlive = true;
            lAlive = true;

        }

        /**
         * Called automatically after a repaint request<br>
         * THIS METHOD SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED! ..
         */
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            draw((Graphics2D) offScreenGraphics);
            g.drawImage(offScreenBuffer, 0, 0, this);
        }

        /**
         * renders all objects to Graphics g
         */
        public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
            super.paint(g);// refresh the background
            if (mAlive == true) {
                Mario.draw(g);
            }
            if (lAlive == true) {
                Luigi.draw(g);
            }
            g.drawImage(img[9], 0, 0, null);
            int lx = Luigi.getBody().x;
            int ly = Luigi.getBody().y;
            int mx = Mario.getBody().x;
            int my = Mario.getBody().y;

            g.setColor(Color.green);
            if (lAlive == true) {

                if (Luigi.getDirection() == -1 && ly >= 420)
                    g.drawImage(img[0], lx, ly, null);
                else if (Luigi.getDirection() == -1 && ly < 420)
                    g.drawImage(img[2], lx, ly, null);
                else if (Luigi.getDirection() == 1 && ly < 420)
                    g.drawImage(img[3], lx, ly, null);
                else
                    g.drawImage(img[1], lx, ly, null);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            if (mAlive == true) {

                if (Mario.getDirection() == -1 && my >= 420)
                    g.drawImage(img[4], mx, my, null);
                else if (Mario.getDirection() == -1 && my < 420)
                    g.drawImage(img[6], mx, my, null);
                else if (Mario.getDirection() == 1 && my < 420)
                    g.drawImage(img[7], mx, my, null);
                else
                    g.drawImage(img[5], mx, my, null);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString(title, 100, 20);// draw the title towards the top
            g.drawRect(BORDER.x, BORDER.y, BORDER.width - 1, BORDER.height - 1);
            g.setFont(f);
            g.drawString("Score:  " + frameCount + " Highscore: " + highScore, 450,
                    100);// approximate middle
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (Rectangle Alien : aliens) {
                g.drawRect(Alien.x, Alien.y, Alien.width, Alien.height);
                g.drawImage(img[8], Alien.x, Alien.y, null);
            }

            // YOUR CODE GOES HERE..
            // render all game objects here
        }

        /**
         * Called automatically when the timer fires<br>
         * this is where all the game fields will be updated
         */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Luigi.move();
            Mario.move();

            if (Math.random() < 0.05) {
                aliens.add(new Rectangle(BORDER.width,
                        448 - (int) (Math.random() * 40),
                        (int) (Math.random() * 15 + 1), 0));
            }

            for (Rectangle Alien : aliens) {
                Alien.x -= Alien.width;
            }
            if (aliens.size() < 0 && aliens.get(0).x == 0) {
                aliens.remove(0);
            }

            /**
             * write a loop to subtract the width of each Rectangle from its
             * x-coordinate write the code to remove the first Rectangle of aliens
             * if its x-coordinate is less than 0
             **/

            Rectangle Alien;
            for (int i = 0; i < aliens.size(); i++) {
                Alien = aliens.get(i);
                // checks right area for intersection but keeps velocity random
                if (Luigi.getBody().intersects(Alien.x, Alien.y, 30, 32) == true) {
                    lAlive = false;
                    if (mAlive == false) {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                    if (frameCount > highScore) {
                        highScore = frameCount + 1;

                    }
                }
                if (Mario.getBody().intersects(Alien.x, Alien.y, 30, 32) == true) {
                    mAlive = false;
                    if (lAlive == false) {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                    if (frameCount > highScore) {
                        highScore = frameCount + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            frameCount++;// used for the score
            repaint();// needed to refresh the animation

        }

        /**
         * handles any key pressed events and updates the player's direction by
         * setting their direction to either 1 or -1 for right or left respectively
         * and updates their jumping status by invoking jump()
         */
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                Luigi.setDirection(-1);
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                Luigi.setDirection(1);
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                Luigi.jump();
            }

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                Mario.setDirection(-1);
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                Mario.setDirection(1);
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                Mario.jump();
            }
        }

        /**
         * handles any key released events and updates the player's direction by
         * setting their direction to 0 if they need to stop and restarts the game
         * if the Timer is not running and user types 'r'
         */
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && Luigi.getDirection() == -1) {
                Luigi.setDirection(0);
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && Luigi.getDirection() == 1) {
                Luigi.setDirection(0);
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_R) {
                if (!timer.isRunning()) {
                    timer.start();
                    initRound();
                }

            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A && Mario.getDirection() == -1) {
                Mario.setDirection(0);
            } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D && Mario.getDirection() == 1) {
                Mario.setDirection(0);
            }

        }

        /**
         * this method is needed for implementing interface KeyListener<br>
         * THIS METHOD SHOULD NOT BE MODIFIED! ..
         */
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

    }// end class EscapeFromRectangulus
```

Comment: Applets don't have main methods. You really should be calling super.paint from within paint and not draw, you could solve the issue its trying to solve by using a JPanel, which is automatically double buffered. Applets have a life cycle which is normally managed by the applet plugin, which you're not, which probably accounts for your error. Based on your error and code, your offScreenBuffer is null

Comment: Applets are officially dead, the plugin is deprecated and no longer supported and most browsers actively block the applet plugin. I'd stick with JPanel, but you need to call init before you add it the window (or convert init to a constructor)

Comment: I'd also do some research into the key bindings API, they will cause you less issues then KeyListener

Comment: *"Trouble Converting JPanel to JApplet"* Applets are always trouble. 
1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: *"This works fine when I have JPanel in Place of JApplet but I want it to run on a webpage."* Oh, I missed that bit. Launch the panel (in a frame) from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). It is the ***only*** practical way to get a rich client Java app. on-screen on the client computer. The code will need to be digitally signed (just as for an applet).